# necessary condition of strict local minimizer

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Given a function $f(x)$ which has up to 2 order continuous derivatives.

It is known that if $f(x)$ attains local minimum at $x=x_0$, then $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)\geq 0$.

I am wondering what is the necessary condition of strict local minimizer, i.e., if $f(x)$ attains strict local minimum at $x=x_0$, what can we deduce from it?

(I understand that $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)> 0$ is not necessary.)

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean necessary inestead of sufficient in the second sentence? Otherwise consider $x^3$ and $x_0=0$. For the question I'm not sure I've ever seen a *necessary* condition for a *strict* min/max.

Comment: @Jose27 I meant necessary condition in the second sentence. Yes I've ever seen neither. I think we can only say $f'(x_0)=0$ and $f''(x_0)\geq 0$.